# System overlay window with Android NDK C++, inc. OpenGL-ES for graphics

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk, homescreen, cocos2d-x-3.x, home-screen-widget

I am very experienced with Visual C++ and I am just starting to program native Android C++ apps with **Visual Studio 2015 C++**.

I need to do a homescreen overlay-style app, presumably by using a **TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY** window and **SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW** permission.

1. Is it possible to do this with the NDK? Will all required API calls be available to use?
2. Am I correct to assume that I **won't** be able to use **OpenGL-ES** to display my graphics in the window (since it isn't **full-screen**)? I would love to be able to use **cocos2d-x** for graphics, input etc but I have a feeling that won't be possible at all.
3. Is it just going to be too difficult to use **NDK for this type of app**, and should preferably just sit down and learn **Java** and **SDK**?
   (last question is probably a bit opinional)

Comment: You definitely can't use OpenGL on android. Presumably you want to use OpenGL-es.

Comment: @BDL Presumably I meant Gl Es!

Comment: FWIW, you can do OpenGL on some Android devices: http://jamesdolan.blogspot.ca/2014/06/opengl-44-and-beyond-on-android.html

Comment: @MuertoExcobito Thanks, but that is getting uncomfortably off topic :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android, anything you can do with Java, you can do with the NDK, because you can simply use [JNI](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html). If you are making many calls into Java from the NDK, you should consider creating an JNI wrapper class, which reduces the calling mechanism to fewer lines.

Although I haven't tried it, there is nothing in the Android documentation to suggest that `GLSurfaceView` cannot be used with a particular type of window layout.